# setOnClickListener Not working in particular class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my code for a one of many buttons within my UserActivity class that don't seem to work even though they have exactly the same implementation in other classes and work there.

```
Button test = findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "An error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
```

Here is the same implementation that works in SignUp class

```
    Button btnLinkToLogIn = findViewById(R.id.btn_link_login);
    btnLinkToLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

If any other code is needed please let me know, I am new to this site as well so please be nice and thanks for your help and taking time to read through this!

[UserActivity.java](https://pastebin.com/GVaqmhVC)

[SignUpActivty.java](https://pastebin.com/qEbgNzE1)

[Project Zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PaKAEK4RJ0_3vf4BRecOsGcIhyuKJq_k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: call finish(); after startactivity

Comment: Paste your xml code. everything looks good in java file.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I added finish(); after startactivity in my useractivity class and still doesn't work

Comment: Hi maybe I can post a zip? I am also having issues with text not displaying in the useractivity class where voice commands should be outputted

Comment: @am2005 Use StackOverflow code snippets to post the codes. Don't use external websites/links to show your code.

Comment: Your code samples on pastebin are going to expire in 6 days and then your question will be meaningless. Please, use the StackOverflow code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given **onClick = "buttonClicked"** in your UserActivity's XML file and you have implemented as shown below. Use either onClick in XML or set onClickListener in your Java file. Dont do both.

```
public void buttonClicked(View view) {
            aiService.startListening();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your project everything is working fine. You must check your device internet connection, rest everything is working fine.

Comment: Did you import the project as a zip?